# Triggering build on Bamboo for pull requests on Stash?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I want to know if it is possible to configure something similar to what is accomplished by Jenkins+Github with [the request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+pull+request+builder+plugin). Specifically, triggering a build on Bamboo when a pull request is created on Stash, using the pull request branch for the build.

Bonus points for triggering new builds when the pull request is updated, or if some command is given through comments (like with the Jenkins plugin).

I can't see a way to do that, and I can't even see a way to create a *plugin* that will make it possible. Maybe the Merge-checks trigger for plugins would work, but it looks like something triggered when someone goes look at the pull request, not something triggered when a pull request arrives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We solved this by writing a Stash plugin, which has now been open sourced and is available on [github](https://github.com/RichRelevance/StashPRTriggerPlugin).

The trick is to annotate methods with `com.atlassian.event.api.EventListener`, which will get Stash to call them when a corresponding event happens. Then just listen to events such as:

- `com.atlassian.stash.event.pull.PullRequestCommentAddedEvent`
- `com.atlassian.stash.event.pull.PullRequestOpenedEvent`
- `com.atlassian.stash.event.pull.PullRequestReopenedEvent`
- `com.atlassian.stash.event.pull.PullRequestRescopedEvent`

Aside from that, just follow Atlassian guidelines to create plugins. The open sourced plugin can serve as a reference.

Answer (score -2):

Stash and Bamboo integration is standard in Atlassian.

Please see:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Bamboo+integration

Comment: I looked at it again just to see if this was recently introduced, but, no, it is still not supported. Please see the question you answered incorrectly.